# Root shell mistakenly changed. How can I change it back to a valid shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I mistakenly entered

```
chsh -s /usr/bin
```

instead of

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and now I can't log into a root shell, how do I start a bash shell as root manually ?

Comment: in what context did you do this. In a current terminal, for the users default shell?

Comment: dont you have users in the sudo group?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I do but when I run `sudo bash` or `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash`it asks me for a password and whether I give the one from the user or from root it says `chsh: PAM: Authentication failure`

Comment: does `sudo vipw` work?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes it did thanks, I wasn't aware I could change the default root shell in that file

Comment: _Not necessary in this case,_ but when you have inadvertently create a catastrophe involving root, you can usually take the machine to single user mode, fix the problem, and then return to multi-user mode.

Comment: @boardrider, and [sometimes rebooting the machine to single-user mode is the **worst possible** thing you can do](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html).

Comment: Indeed, @Wildcard, if one encounters the aftermath of a `cd / && rm -rf *` some thinking and unconventional measures would be necessary. In my comment, I was referring to the other 99% of root-related catastrophes (and, even for that 1%, you may need to get to single-user at some point ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While root does not have access, a user in the sudo group can still run privileged commands - it seems the error is not in sudo, but elsewhere in the `sudo chsh`command (e.g. chsh error).

As such your sudo is apparently working.

The passwd file can be edited with:

```
sudo vipw
```

And the root shell changed manually.

(first line of `/etc/passwd` usually)

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Fom man [vipw](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw)

> The vipw and vigr commands edits the files /etc/passwd and /etc/group,
>   respectively. With the -s flag, they will edit the shadow versions of
>   those files, /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow, respectively. The programs
>   will set the appropriate locks to prevent file corruption.

Comment: I never knew about `vipw` and `vigr`, thank you! I always used `sudo vim /etc/passwd`

Comment: You might be interested in `visudo` http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/visudo.man.html  too, @tac

Comment: Or `sudo -e`, that performs this locking-editing feature for any edit.

Answer (score 16):

Another option, assuming you have access to another account, is to manually override the default shell by using `su --shell=/bin/bash`:

> -s, --shell=SHELL
>   run SHELL if /etc/shells allows it

The primary advantage of this is that it only requires access to another account, not another *privileged* one.

Answer (score 8):

For security reasons, logins whether textual or graphical and utilities like `su` and `sudo` that allow you to run commands as a different user all run those command through the target user's shell. If the target user's shell is non-functional, well, you've seen the results :-(

Unless you happen to have a still-functional root shell running somewhere or something like a setuid-root binary or something that allows you to bypass this, rebooting and correcting the problem using a rescue system or live image is probably your best bet.

Boot the rescue system, mount your real system's root filesystem somewhere, say, `/mnt/foo`, and edit `/mnt/foo/etc/passwd` to fix the shell. Save, unmount, and you're done.

Comment: curious, what happens if you do this and the /etc/passwd file is in a hash instead of plain text?

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is not plaintext? I haven't seen that in at least, like, a decade. Is that still a thing on some systems? Anyway, I guess `chroot /mnt/foo chsh -s /bin/bash` might do the trick in that case?

Comment: I have never had the problem described, however I work with locked down systems that need to have /etc/passwd not in plain text as to avoid hackers and the such compromising the system even more if they gain access. Hmm that might work, lets just say I hope i never have to try and see if it works actually.

Comment: I was able to edit /etc/passwd with sudo from a user account, I wasn't aware that the shell was defined in this file, thanks

Comment: @ChiseledAbs oh, you were? Good for you, glad you solved your problem. I didn't think it would let you.

Answer (score 7):

Add `init=/bin/bash` to your kernel command line ( if booting with grub, press `e` to edit the boot entry ), and you will have a bash shell running as root without even having to supply a password.  Your root filesystem likely will still be mounted read only though, so you will need to remount it first, then you can change the shell back with `chsh`.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jdoe`

will change the shell of *jdoe* to `bash`. You can then `sudo egrep jdoe /etc/passwd` to verify.